# Using a second Wifi Router (in order to use a LAN port)

Tags: router, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Problem: Connecting a TV decoder via Internet. It doesn't have inbuilt wifi so wired LAN is the only option. I bought a second Wifi Router so I could use its LAN port to create a wired internet connection to my decoder.

What I want to achieve:
The second Wifi Router should basically pick up the signal from the main wifi router. I would then use the LAN port to connect (with a wire) to the TV decoder. In other words have my secondary Wifi Router act as an access point, which will enable me to use a wired LAN connection to the decoder.

What i've done so far:
Connected the second Wifi Router to my laptop via the LAN ports. Access 192.168.1.1 and went into my second router. 1) SSID set to the same one as the main Wifi Router 2) Tried disabling DHCP and enabling DHCP (with the DNS and default gateway configured the same as the main router).

When I check my network connections, I see the LAN connection too but it says 'Not connected to the internet' while the Wifi (main router) shows connected.

Can someone please advise on how to use my second Wifi Router to connect to the main Wifi Router (and thus the Internet).

Thanks.

main wifi router: Zyxel
secondary wifi router: TP Link

Comment: Could you add a picture to make your explanation a bit clearer? I guess you want to create a wireless bridge between the two rouuters and cable the decoder into the second router?

Comment: Here's a pictorial description of what i'm trying to do. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=22xr4&s=5#.UmEzjPndeMM

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I managed to switch the TP Link as the main router connected via ethernet to WAN and using the Zyxel as the Client router (with 192.168.1.2) to work as an access point. I was checking online and found a firmware upgrade from zyxel after which the Wifi just doesn't work. So i'm kind of stuck at the moment. Thanks again for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to achieve is wireless bridging, where you're connecting two networks via wireless instead of via physical cable.  Generally speaking, putting two routers on the same SSID doesn't make them function on the same network inherently.  Your routers must explicitly support wireless bridging to take advantage of it, otherwise, you're better off physically linking both routers.

Without knowing the specific model, I can't say for sure if your wireless routers support that functionality.

That being said, you should opt for the wired option.

**Update (wireless bridging configurations):**

For the ZyXel, go to page 56/Chapter 4.5 of the [NBG-416N User Manual](http://prodotti.zyxel.it/USERSGUIDE/ZYXNBG-416N.pdf)

For the TP Link, go to page 28/Chapter 4.6 of the [TL WR543G User Manual](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/software/2008716160729.pdf)

Comment: Zyxel  NBG-416N is the main router and TP Link TL WR543G is the second.

The reason I ask is because when the guy came to set this up, he made it work and everything was fine, until someone in the house messed with the settings.

Comment: See my update for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The Zyxel does not support wireless bridging but AP client router mode. A wireless bridge is not a router, just a passive component which accepts wired connections on one side, and relays them to the router via wireless. The AP client router is instead a proper router (with DHCP, dnsmasq, advanced routing, the works), which however is connected to the Internet or an ISP via wifi. This is why it is called a Router which has an AP-client
connection on the Wan side.

This being said, instructions for connections are straightforward, on your manual. But keep in mind:

1. you must enable the DHCP server. Since you are behind a router (not a wireless bridge), no one else can provide internal IP addresses.
2. you must choose a LAN net which does not conflict with the network set up by the Zyxel. In fact, suppose both networks were 192.168.1.0/24. How would your TP-Link know whether a request to talk to 192.168.1.13 (say) means someone on the LAN side, or on the WAN side? So, please pick a LAN-side subnet of the TP-Link that differs from that of the Zyxel. I am assuming you know how to check the IP range povided by the Zyxel. 
   Apart from this, the default parameters suggested by your manual are fine.
3. For the WAN connection, choose Dynamic IP: there's no reason to do otherwise.
4. Also, gievn the previous three caveats, the quick installation guide is enough for the kind of connection you are envisioning.